# Linear regression with statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a linear regression model implemented in statsmodels library. The distribution of the error term is a t-distribution with (sigma>0 and dof>2) as depicted below.

Is it possible to produce such a likelihood in statsmodels, making use of generic likelihood method?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a test and example case for GenericLikelihoodModel in statsmodels.

see https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.miscmodels.tmodel.TLinearModel.html
for the TLinearModel and the source code for how to implement generic maximum likelihood models.

Some examples are in the unit tests https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/miscmodels/tests/test_tmodel.py

Comment: Josef, thanks for your answer. I marked your answer as the correct one. I wasn't yet familiar with the miscmodels in statsmodels.